# Get Count of Affected rows of SQL table

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I would like to know how can I get the count of affected rows when using the `SqlDataAdapter` class. Does this line return the no. of affected rows?

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = command;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adapter.UpdateCommand` doesn't execute the query, it just sets the SqlCommand for Updates and it doesn't return anything.

`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` returns just the number or affected rows in the update statement:

```
int affectedRows = adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also you have the same information returned by `adapter.Update`

```
int affectedRows = adapter.Update(dataSet);
```

Docs for [SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure used to
>   update records in the data source.

Docs for [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns
>   the number of rows affected.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice Explanation! Really helped!

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery - returns the number of rows affected.

```
SqlCommand comm;
// other codes
int numberOfRecords = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```